# Custom Webpart doesn't show up in Sharepoint 2010 after deploying from VS2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Full disclosure: Sharepoint development noob. I currently have 3 custom web parts built in an SP solution in VS2010. I build and deploy my project out to our local Sharepoint dev box. However, after deploying, only the first 2 custom web parts show up under the Custom category in the "insert web part" ribbon section. I checked the elements.xml file for all 3 webparts, they're all set up to be listed under the custom group. Any ideas on how I can debug this? Any constructive advice is greatly appreciated.

Home elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="Home" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="Home\Home.webpart" Url="Home.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

IdeaEditor elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="IdeaEditor" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="IdeaEditor\IdeaEditor.webpart" Url="IdeaEditor.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

IdeaGrid elements.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" >
  <Module Name="IdeaGrid" List="113" Url="_catalogs/wp">
    <File Path="IdeaGrid\IdeaGrid.webpart" Url="IdeaGrid.webpart" Type="GhostableInLibrary" >
      <Property Name="Group" Value="Custom" />
    </File>
  </Module>
</Elements>
```

Comment: have you checked the actual webpart file to see if it has any errors. Why dont you post the webpart file that has a problem

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem too, be shure NOT do upgrade solution, cause new webparts are not shown !
Try a retract uninstall and fresh installation instead